# Why is the function undefined?

Tags: javascript

```js
(function(window){
  var devigner = window.devigner = {};
  devigner.create = function() {      /*a generic method to create elements */
    var element = function() {

    };
  };
})(window);
```

The above code has an error for document.create.element being undefined while the typeof devigner is object which is correct , but typeof devigner.create is function.

[when run in firebug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xj8b.png)

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit.Also what is `document.create.element`?

Comment: You have to call the function document.create().element

Comment: `element` is a local variable of `devigner.create`. It cannot be accessed outside of the function without returning it or using a closure.

Comment: Is `devigner.create` suppose to be a constructor, an object with methods or a function... with another function tacked on to it?

Comment: Did you mean to define as `devigner.create = function() { }; devigner.create.element = function() { };`?

Comment: WTH , OK, thanks everyone, i got it,. another very big silly mistake my me.

Comment: 4castle yes i that's what i planned. Thanks.

Comment: The code you give does nothing at all. What are you trying to acomplish? If there is some error when you try to **invoke** `window.devigner`, then please show how you call it, and what the resulting error is. Apparently, you think that declaring a local variable `element` inside a function being assigned to a property such as `devigner.create` somehow magically places it as a property on that function. Why would you think that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the function:

```
document.create().element
```

Also, create function should return an object with an 'element' value

```
create = function() {
    var element = ....
    ....
    return {element: element}
}
```

Comment: Great to see that this community is that helpful, BTW i got the point, thanks for making me learn.

Comment: i just did. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, I doubt it that's what he wants, or if that's the best way to do it. He seems to merely need to say `devigner.create = {element: function()...`.